# .openDialog() method doesnt load page in TFS 2017

Tags: javascript, tfs, azure-devops

I have a button on 2017 TFS work item form. It should open a dialog.

I used this Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/using-host-dialog) and made the following code:

```
$(us_button[0]).click(function(){
    VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.Dialog).then(function(dialogService) {
        var extensionCtx = VSS.getExtensionContext();
        // Build absolute contribution ID for dialogContent
        var contributionId = extensionCtx.publisherId + "." + extensionCtx.extensionId + ".info";

        // Show dialog
        var dialogOptions = {
            title: "My Dialog",
            width: 800,
            height: 600
        };
        dialogService.openDialog(contributionId, dialogOptions);
    }); 
});
```

I also added an `info` element in manifest as Microsoft’s guide suggests.

It does open a window, but never loads the page `info.html`.
The only thing debug says is `(no stack) null`.

Manifest file:

```
{
"manifestVersion": 1,
"id": "usButton",
"version": "1.0.56",
"name": "usButton",
"publisher": "Logrocon",
"icons": {
    "default": "img/logo.png"
},
"targets": [
    {
        "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
    }
],
"tags": [
    "Work Item",
    "Work Item control"
],
"files": [
    {
        "path": "img",
        "addressable": true
    },
    {
        "path": "dist",
        "addressable": true
    },
    {
      "path": "scripts/main.js",
      "contentType": "text/javascript",
      "addressable": true
    },
    {
        "path": "info.html",
        "addressable": true
    },

    {
        "path": "usButton.html",
        "addressable": true
    }
],
"categories": [
    "Plan and track"
],
"scopes": [
    "vso.work_write"
],
"contributions": [
        {
        "id": "usButton",
        "type": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-control",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "usButton",
            "uri": "usButton.html",
            "height": 40,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "id": "FieldAppTestBtn",
                    "description": "Autocalculate Remaining Work.",
                    "type": "WorkItemField",
                    "properties": {
                        "workItemFieldTypes": ["Double"]
                    },
                    "validation": {
                        "dataType": "String",
                        "isRequired": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "info",
        "targets": [],
        "description": "The content to be displayed in the dialog",
        "type": "ms.vss-web.control",
        "properties": {
            "uri": "info.html"
        }
    }        
]
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that it opens a blank window? Could you please share the extension package for troubleshooting? (source code would be better if possible, just zip the extension folder and share in OneDrive, then share the link here)

Comment: Can you also share the content in manifest file?

Comment: @Andy-MSFT is opens a window, try to download page inside, fails, gives some error, it`s Russian TFS, so text is in Russian, but point of error is what he cant load my extension.  Here is link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvjUpBy-VJIjatWCUAoBgjjhtw4

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I added it to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't import the extension SDK and `run VSS.init()` method in the info.html. Update it to below and then try again:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color:inherit;height:100%;">
    <head>
        <title>Continious delivery actions</title>
        <script src="dist/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:inherit;height:100%;">
        <div><table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Поле</td><td>Значение</td></tr></table></div>
        <script>
            VSS.init();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```